# Render FOSUserBundle form on homepage

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

I want to render fos user bundle on my homepage, and action of this form direct to login page. Here is what I have tried thus far:

`{% render "FOSUserBundle::Security::login" %}` 
Which throws me this error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("No
>   route found for "GET :Security::login"")

I also tried

```
{{ render(controller('FOSUserBundle:Security:login')) }}
```

But it gives me a blank page.

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong ? Thanks.

Comment: This is too broad. Post what you have tried so far. FOSUserBundle's [documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md)  is a good place to start.

Comment: {% render "FOSUserBundle::Security::login" %} - but doesn't work. An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("No route found for "GET :Security::login"")

Comment: {{ render(controller('FOSUserBundle:Security:login')) }} - gives me blank page.

Comment: put updates and all related code inside your post and not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

This way should do the trick:

```
{% render url('fos_user_security_login') %}
```